# Detect that lock screen is engaged, windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, lockscreen, credential-providers

I'm developing a v2 credential provider for windows 8/10 and I want to detect the state of the lock screen. I need to skip some actions in ICredentialProviderCredential2::SetSelected() if the lock screen is active or execute it if logonUI screen with tiles is displayed. How can I do it?